# Notepad++: Find and replace using regular expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I apologize if it sounds dumb to you, but I need to find `__( 'anyTextHere', 'foo' )` and replace all of the instances with `'anyTextHere'`.

Basically, I just want to retain `'anyTextHere'`, then delete the rest.

Sample code:

```
    __( 'beach', 'foo' )
    __( 'summer', 'foo' )
```

then find:

```
    __( 'anyTextHere', 'foo' )
```

and when replaced with regular expressions, the result should be:

```
    'beach'
    'summer'
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for

```
 __\( '([^']*)', 'foo' \)
```

and replace with `$1`

To be more general:

```
__\( '([^']*)', '[^']*' \)
```

and replace also with `$1`

Comment: @cblab I tested it in v6.1.2 works fine. Probably they changed it when they introduced PCRE regex in v6.0

Comment: @stema ah ok, my mistake, so. Good news, BTW.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace

```
__\( '([']+), [^)]+)
```

by `'\1'`